# Error - Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context

Tags: flutter, dart, lifecycle, page-lifecycle

i call the data i get from the service in didChangeDependencies to reflect it on the page. Because when i call this in initState, i'm facing an error. Anyway, this is not my main problem. My main problem is when page loaded, i got datas but when i want to go previous page, im facing a problem :
"Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct)."
"Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active."
According to my research, i should use "mounted" in if state. But it didn't work.
Also i tried if statement like this:

```
@override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }
```

[These are errors i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoteM.png)

My code:

```
List<DetailObjects?> onOdemeDetay = [];

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    OnOdemeListeClass().fetchList(context).then((value) {
      final checkData = Provider.of<LoginInfo>(context, listen: false);
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          if (value != null && value.detailObjects != null) {
            onOdemeDetay = value.detailObjects!;
            checkData.updateLabel(onOdemeDetay[0]?.label);
            checkData.updateValue(onOdemeDetay[0]?.value);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the state before going to previous page, you have to add delay of 2 seconds, which means when user press back button, firstly state will be update and then user will navigate to previous page.

```
 onPressed: () {

  //First Update your state here

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
     //Code to navigate previous page
  });
},
```

Comment: I dont know how to reach navigator.push's backbutton code thats why i removed it and added iconbutton. So my problem is solved, thank you so much!